# how can I add border on my javascript Balls in canvas?

Tags: javascript, border

i found code for making moving balls in canvas.
now i can change ball's color but i want to make them with 1px border.
I am super beginner and tried to many things.. but Can not make them.
please help me..
here is code :

```
var canvas = {
element: document.getElementById('canvas'),
width: 1000,
height: 1000,
initialize: function () {
  this.element.style.width = this.width + 'px';
  this.element.style.height = this.height + 'px';
  document.body.appendChild(this.element);
}
};

var Ball = {
create: function (color, dx, dy) {
  var newBall = Object.create(this);
  newBall.dx = dx;
  newBall.dy = dy;
  newBall.width = 40;
  newBall.height = 40;
  newBall.element = document.createElement('div');
  newBall.element.style.backgroundColor = color;
  newBall.element.style.strokeStyle = "black";
  newBall.element.style.width = newBall.width + 'px';
  newBall.element.style.height = newBall.height + 'px';
  newBall.element.className += ' ball';
  newBall.width = parseInt(newBall.element.style.width);
  newBall.height = parseInt(newBall.element.style.height);
  canvas.element.appendChild(newBall.element);
  return newBall;
},
moveTo: function (x, y) {
  this.element.style.left = x + 'px';
  this.element.style.top =y + 'px';
},
changeDirectionIfNecessary: function (x, y) {
  if (x < 0 || x > canvas.width - this.width) {
      this.dx = -this.dx;
  }
  if (y < 0 || y > canvas.height - this.height) {
      this.dy = -this.dy;
  }
},
draw: function (x, y) {
  this.moveTo(x, y);
  var ball = this;
  setTimeout(function () {
      ball.changeDirectionIfNecessary(x, y);
      ball.draw(x + ball.dx, y + ball.dy);
  }, 1000 / 60);
}
};

canvas.initialize();
var ball1 =  Ball.create("blue", 4, 3);
var ball2 =  Ball.create("blue", 1, 5);
var ball3 =  Ball.create("blue", 2, 2);

ball1.draw(70, 0);
ball2.draw(20, 200);
ball3.draw(300, 330);
```

where should i put something about border in here?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have added the `ball` class to all your balls, you can easily accomplish this with CSS (I would recommend you handle your styling inside of your css and not your javascript).

```css
.ball {
  border 1px solid white;
}
```

You can read more about the syntax and what those value mean at the documentation (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border).

If you decide you don't want to handle this in your style sheet, you can apply this style directly onto each ball in much the same manner.

```js
newBall.element.style.border = '1px solid white';
```